# How to I remove files from .gitignore?

Tags: git

I've found all kinds of answers about how to add files to .gitignore (i.e. make git ignore files that were previously tracked), but I can't seem to figure out the reverse.

I have a .gitignore that has certain files in it being ignored that I no longer want to be ignored. I've removed the files from the .gitignore file, but they're still being ignored when I do commits. What do I need to do to make git start tracking these files again?

Comment: So you've committed the updated `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Normally you just do nothing. What commands do you apply to commit? Can you give an example?

Comment: @sjagr - yes, I've committed the gitignore.

Comment: @Lol4t0 - I use TortoiseGit, so I just choose the Commit command from the menu, then check which untracked files to add. The files I want aren't even in the list of currently untracked files.

Comment: If you can afford to run something at the command line, run `git check-ignore <path>`, where `<path>` is the path to a file that is (undesirably) being ignored. It should tip you off on what is going on.

Comment: @EmmyS do you have option to "add to git" files. From file manager for example. However, console should help you anyway

Comment: @Jubobs `check-ignore`'s `-v` option can be very helpful

Comment: @jthill I've never had to use it but I'll remember that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

### Places to Check for Ignored Files

In addition to your repository's `.gitignore` file, you may also have things ignored in a global `~/.gitignore` or `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`, or in the repository's `.git/info/exclude` file. You should ensure all of them have been updated, and that your file is not listed in any of them.

Also check the value of `core.excludesfile` (see [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)) both globally and locally to see if you have it set to something custom. And finally, you can check whether a particular file is really being ignored and where that's been specified by using [git-check-ignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore). For example:

```
git check-ignore --verbose <some_file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `git add file_that_you_want_to_include` in console for each file that you want to be included, or just `git add -A` - it will include all files, except files mentioned in `.gitignore`. And don't forget to commit your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove a file from the .gitignore list Git will stop ignoring it. However, if it has been ignoring it thus far it will not recognize any changes made to that file while it was ignored. To make those changes apparent to Git, make at least one more change to that file after delisting it.

As a side-note, you do not need to commit .gitignore in order for changes made to it to take affect locally.